# Does TFS 2015 Team Buider that uses MSBuild order building of projects properly according to dependencies stored in solution file?

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

My solution consists from C# projects. I need one build definition that builds the whole solution. Most of projects have project to project referencies (like ProjectReference Include=) but some projects have explicit dependencies stored in solution file (ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) in sln file).

[old connect.microsoft.com article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586358/msbuild-ignores-projectsection-projectdependencies-in-sln-file-and-attempts-to-build-projects-in-wrong-order)

claims that MSBuild ignores order specified in solution "Project dependencies". Are situation the same in TFS 2015? What MSBuild version does TFS 2015 use nowadays?

Does TFS 2015 Team Buider that uses MSBuild order building of projects properly according to dependencies stored in solution file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does, at least on solutions I have seen (consisting of 10-15 projects) dependencies never give issues.

Additionally TFS2015 have Visual Studio build step which is run not by standalone msbuild but Visual Studio installed on the build server. Naturally this build step completely replicates your local build behavior.

Comment: Thank you. Does TFS2015 Visual Studio build step (that runs Visual Studio installed on build server) show full VS build output?

Comment: Per my experience yes. The principle that you install full Visual Studio on build server reassures me that this is how it works. I can even use extensions installed in Visual Studio (for example NUnit adapter).

Comment: If you expect something specific in the logs, let me know I can check logs.